# If Empty Loop in Excel VBA exiting prematurely

Tags: excel, vba

quick question, what looks wrong in the code below (to find the first non-zero row) ? It keeps exiting the loop, although the first non-zero row is row 5, and not row 2 :(

```
'Finding first non-zero row
    y = 2
    If IsEmpty(Range(Cells(y, 10).Address)) = True Then
    Do
     y = y + 1
    Loop While IsEmpty(Range(Cells(y, 10).Address)) = True
End If

FirstRow = y
```

Really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Why do you use an `if` and `loop while` with the same condition, when you can do that with `do while` and just have the condition once? Also, there is no use in adding `= True` to the condition, because  `IsEmpty()` already returns a boolean. Then also `IsEmpty(Cells(y, 10)` should be enough. It is overkill to get address string and then convert back with `Range` to what `Cells` already returned.

Comment: Are you sure you have mentioned the right column number? Column 10 is column `J`...

Answer (score 1):

The code should run fine, just make sure that you are looking in the right column: column 10 is column `J`, which might not be the one you expected to look in.

There are however several things to improve to your code:

- You don't need an `If`. Just use `Do While` instead to get the same sequence of checking;
- there is no use in adding `= True` to the condition, because `IsEmpty()` already returns a `Boolean`;
- `IsEmpty(Cells(y, 10))` should be enough to make the check. It is overkill to get the cell's address string and then convert that back with `Range()` to what `Cells()` already returned.

Code:

```
y = 2
Do While IsEmpty(Cells(y, 10))
    y = y + 1
Loop
FirstRow = y
```

Answer (score -1):

Both of your `IsEmpty` lines should check for False, not True.

Comment: For finding a non-zero row, one needs to continue searching while a row is empty.

Comment: @Space_girl - did you change both? Changing the first will get you in the loop, changing the second will keep you in the loop.

Comment: @OldUgly I don't think false is the way to go, it has to be checking for true ! it works now strangely, will test further though

Comment: @trincot - I think "zero row" is meant to be "empty row". To find a "non-empty row" you keep searching while "Not IsEmpty" or "IsEmpty = False"

Comment: @OldUgly, just read slowly what you just wrote. If you do that you will stop looping where `IsEmpty = True`.

Comment: all good people, my problem is solved, notice that in my code I'm not looking for the first non-empty row to be spitted out, im asking that while it is empty, keep doing row = row + 1, so that one finally gets to a non-empty row while empty is true.

Comment: @trincot - I love working with multiple levels of negative logic. Properly chastised. 8)